# WebSocket Networking Plugin Unreal Engine v4.22.3

Tags: plugins, websocket, unreal-engine4

how can I add **WebSocket Networking Plugin** into Unreal v 4.22.3?
I know is already listed with the other plugins in other Unreal versions, but looks is not included in this version ( 4.22.3 )
Any help?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: I can't explain why but the plugin was seemingly renamed to "Experimental HTML5 Networking Plugin". Here's the [change](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/commits/release/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/WebSocketNetworking/Source) where it was moved back to its own folder (you'll need an account on github and access to the public epic repo to see). Enabling the html5 plugin is probably the right/easiest thing to do.

Comment: If you need that exact engine version with the WebSocket Networking Plugin from another version. Then i'd take the aforementioned changelist from github and build the engine from source.

Comment: Many thanks @George I'm going to check it!